# How to generate a text using keywords which should look similar to the sentence I have?

Tags: nlp

I have a text,

```
    text = 'Morning Sue, I wondered if we could catch up this week, 19th?I wanted to discuss the quote I sent last week B-GreW2020-026 for my aviation policy. I think it had a limit of £30,000,000 and an excess of £200,000. Let me know what works for you? Shall we include Willis into the call from a brokerage perspective?'
```

I have an excel file,

```
                  Ref_no            Limit    Excess 
              Co-MS N2020-501     3471463    520000
```

I would like to generate a text like above sentence using the keywords from excel? I am sure there's a way to do this with AI. I ready about text augmentation as well. I know this can be done using regex but I am looking for a way using sentence generator. Kindly help.

Expected output:

```
  Output = 'Morning Sue, I wondered if we could catch up this week, 19th?I wanted to discuss the quote I sent last week Co-MS N2020-501 for my aviation policy. I think it had a limit of £3471463 and an excess of 520000. Let me know what works for you? Shall we include Willis into the call from a brokerage perspective?'
```

Or somewhat related text using the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Few days I came across a library which is solving the same problem and it is call **POINTER**

This will take some keywords and will form multiple sentences using those keywords.

- **Paper** - https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.00558
- **GitHub** - https://github.com/dreasysnail/POINTER
- **Demo** - http://52.247.25.3:8900/